# Debian package creation with debhelper: change dependency version

Tags: debian, package, libstdc++, debhelper

I'm creating a Debian package using DebHelper, under the latest stable version of Debian.

The "debian/control" file comprises these lines:

```
Depends:
 ${shlibs:Depends},
 ${misc:Depends}
```

The dependencies are thus automatically set in the created package. However, the version required of libstdc++ is too strict. The package requires libstdc++6 (**>= 4.9**) and I want it to be set as libstdc++6 (**>= 4.8**).

For this purpose and at the reading of this [page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/dh_makeshlibs.1.html) and this [page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dh.1.html), I edited the "debian/rules" file which now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

DPKG_EXPORT_BUILDFLAGS = 1
include /usr/share/dpkg/buildflags.mk

%:
    dh $@ 

override_dh_makeshlibs:
    dh_makeshlibs -V 'libstdc++6 (>= 4.8)'
```

The last two lines however did not make the job. Has anyone already did this kind of customization on a Debian package?

Thanks

Comment: I've read the documentation and your proposed solution seems valid. When you inspect the resulting `DEBIAN/control` file does it contain any particular version? You said you're building the packge for the latest Debian stable (I assume jessie) which packages `libstdc++6` 4.9.2. Is it necessary under these conditions to relax the version requirement? (In other words wouldn't package targeted for different distribution work better?)

Comment: The resulting DEBIAN/control is what I check after the package is done. I have Jessie which packages lidstdc++4.9.2 as you said. I don't know if it's a good idea but other people said that the software can be built with the version 4.8 so I could relax the version in the package. The package would be thus compatible with other debian-based distributions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, debhelper does a very good job at detecting dependencies.

If it says that your packages requires `libstdc++6 (>= 4.9)`, than your package most likely does require this specific version and will fail with e.g. `libstdc++6-4.8`. (If you don't believe me, try it out; force-install your package on a system that has only libstdc++6-4.8 installed, and see whether *everything* works)

If some people claim that it can be build with `libstd++6-4.8` (or rather `gcc-4.8`), then I see to possibilities:

- either those people are mistaken
- OR the binary (in your package) will be slightly different, depending on whether it was built against libstdc++6-4.8 or 4.9

Most likely the second point is the case.

This can have numerous reasons, e.g.:
- your package automatically enables features if it detects libstdc++6-4.9
- some implementation detail in libstdc++6 has changed which makes the resulting binaries incompatible (or at least: not backwards compatible)

If you want a package that can be used with libstdc++6 == 4.8, than you should use `libstdc++6-4.8` (or most likely: the entire g++4.8 toolchain) for building the package.